# What is the difference between "to benefit from" and "to profit from"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I do not understand when it is more accurate to say "to benefit from" than "to profit from". Are they interchangeable or is there precise context to employ one rather than the other?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research; for example, did you look up "benefit" & "profit" in a dictionary.  If so, what didn't you understand about the definitions?  As it stands, your question is likely to be closed for "lack of research". Please take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Comment: Note that this is an exact duplicate of the question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/209872/what-is-the-difference-between-to-benefit-from-and-to-profit-from).

Comment: I may well have benefited from having vaccinations, but I have not profited from them.

Answer (score 2):

They are both similar in meaning, but "to profit from" implies financial gain, whereas "to benefit from" could refer to any sort of positive result.